# Luigi - Overriding Task requires/input

Tags: python, pipeline, luigi

I am using luigi to execute a chain of tasks, like so:

```
class Task1(luigi.Task):
    stuff = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('test.json')

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write(stuff)


class Task2(luigi.Task):
    stuff = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        return Task1(stuff=self.stuff)

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('something-else.json')

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write(stuff)
```

This works exactly as desired when I start the entire workflow like so:

```
luigi.build([Task2(stuff='stuff')])
```

When using `luigi.build` you can also run multiple tasks by explicitly passing arguments, [as per this example in the documentation](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_luigi.html#running-from-python-code).

However, in my situation, I would also like to be able to run the business logic of `Task2` completely independently of it's involvement in the workflow. This works fine for tasks that do not implement `requires`, [as per this example](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#but-i-just-want-to-run-a-hadoop-job).

My question is, how can I run this method both as part of the workflow, as well as on it's own? Obviously, I could just add a new private method like `_my_custom_run`, which takes the data and returns the result, and then use this method in `run`, but it just feels like something that should be baked into the framework, so it makes me feel like I am misunderstanding Luigi's best practices (still learning the framework). Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want [dynamic requirements.](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/examples/dynamic_requirements.py) Using the pattern shown in that example, you could read a config or pass a parameter with arbitrary data, and `yield` only the tasks that you want to require based on the fields in the config.

```
# tasks.py
import luigi
import json
import time


class Parameterizer(luigi.Task):
    params = luigi.Parameter() # Arbitrary JSON

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('./config.json')

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            json.dump(params, f)

class Task1(luigi.Task):
    stuff = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('{}'.format(self.stuff[:6]))

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write(self.stuff)


class Task2(luigi.Task):
    stuff = luigi.Parameter()
    params = luigi.Parameter()


    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('{}'.format(self.stuff[6:]))

    def run(self):

        config = Parameterizer(params=self.params)
        yield config

        with config.output().open() as f:
            parameters = json.load(f)

        if parameters["runTask1"]:
            yield Task1(stuff=self.stuff)
        else:
            pass
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write(self.stuff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cf_json = '{"runTask1": True}'

    print("Trying to run with Task1...")
    luigi.build([Task2(stuff="Task 1Task 2", params='{"runTask1":true}')], local_scheduler=True)

    time.sleep(10)

    cf_json = '{"runTask1": False}'

    print("Trying to run WITHOUT Task1...")
    luigi.build([Task2(stuff="Task 1Did just task 2", params='{"runTask1":false}')], local_scheduler=True)
```

(This is executed by simply calling `python tasks.py`)

We could easily imagine mapping more than one parameter to more than one task, or applying custom tests before allowing various tasks to execute. We could also rewrite this to take the params from `luigi.Config`.

Also note the following control flow from `Task2`:

```
    if parameters["runTask1"]:
        yield Task1(stuff=self.stuff)
    else:
        pass
```

Here we could run an alternative task, or dynamically call tasks as we saw in the example from the `luigi` repo. For example:

```
    if parameters["runTask1"]:
        yield Task1(stuff=self.stuff)
    else:
        # self.stuff is not automatically parsed to int, so this list comp is valid
        data_dependent_deps = [Task1(stuff=x) for x in self.stuff] 
        yield data_dependent_deps
```

This may be a bit more involved than a simple `run_standalone()` method, but I think it's the closest thing to what you were looking for in the documented luigi patterns.

Source: https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html?highlight=dynamic#dynamic-dependencies